# long javascript if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, refactoring

I've got a long series of if-else statements.  I know there's a more efficient way to do this but am not familiar enough with javascript.  Can someone offer some guidance?

```
$('#webform-component-primary-credential--0').change (function() {
    if ($('#edit-submitted-primary-credential-0').val() == 35) {
      $('#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-47').attr('checked', false);
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-47").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-47").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    if ($('#edit-submitted-primary-credential-0').val() == 41) {
      $('#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-53').attr('checked', false);
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-53").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-53").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    if ($('#edit-submitted-primary-credential-0').val() == 13) {
      $('#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-29').attr('checked', false);
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-29").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-29").removeAttr("disabled");
    }   

});
```

There are about 12 more if-else statements in this series but this gives the general idea.

Comment: Is the `--` in the first selector a typo?

Comment: Note that since jQuery 1.6.1, `.attr()` will not work as expected. Use `.prop()` instead.

Comment: @SalmanA, can you elaborate? What are the cases where it would not work as expected?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - no, not a typo.

Answer (score 6):

Use a switch-case statement, if you're always checking the same value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

(This can also be used in C/C++ and many other languages that borrow syntax from them. Some languages have variations on it, like Ruby's case-when syntax.)

Your code is actually a little bit cumbersome to factor into a switch-case statement (it's best for one long `if () {} else if () {} ... else () {}` chain), but here's one way you could do it:

```
$('#webform-component-primary-credential--0').change (function() {
    var active_element;

    $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-47").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-53").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-29").removeAttr("disabled");

    switch ($('#edit-submitted-primary-credential-0').val()) {
        case 35:
            active_element = $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-47");
            break;
        case 41:
            active_element = $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-53");
            break;
        case 13:
            active_element = $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-29");
            break;
    }

    active_element.attr('checked', false);
    active_element.attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: That wouldn't work out of the box, since her logic is a bit more complicated than just an if with a bunch of elseifs. I'm not convinced a switch case would whittle it down siginificantly.

Comment: @Asad, you're right, but a switch-case could be used to toggle the element being acted on. For instance, in her example, she could do a switch-case to set the current element to 47, 53, or 29, and then continue with the generic logic that would be happening on each one. (In fact, that would make it cleaner even with plain if-else clauses.)

Comment: @Asad, it was a bit different from what I originally thought of, but I added an example that's mostly equivalent to OP's code.

Comment: That's a pretty clean way of doing it. An alternative would be just to make an array `[35,41,13]` etc. and check if the value is in the array. If it is, use something like `$("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-" + val);`

Comment: @Asad, Looks like Matt and Andrew had much the same idea. Personally I think it's much better and clearer in this case to explicitly enumerate the options. It would be even better if these credentials had generic, readable names.

Comment: Once you've isolated the code that selects the active element, it would be even better as its own function.  Then inside your switch cases you can just return the active element and no need for break statements.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this might work:

```
$("#webform-component-primary-credential--0").change(function() {
    var primaryCred = $("#edit-submitted-primary-credential-0").val(), 
        credIdPrefix = "#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-", 
        credMap = { 35 : 47, 41 : 53, 13 : 29 };

    for (var cred in credMap) {
        if (primaryCred == cred) {
            $(credIdPrefix + credMap[cred]).attr({ "checked" : false, "disabled" : "disabled" });
        } else {
            $(credIdPrefix + credMap[cred]).removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is more what I was looking for.  I used this and it works wonderfully!

Comment: @MichelleWilliamson, if the answer works and was what you were looking for, consider accepting it by selecting the big check to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaner and faster way of doing it:

```
$(function() {
    var dependencies, $checkboxes;

    dependencies = {
        35: 47,
        41: 53,
        13: 29
    };

    $checkboxes = $(":checkbox[id^='edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-']");

    $('#webform-component-primary-credential--0').change(function() {
        var primaryCredential, selector;
        primaryCredential = $('#edit-submitted-primary-credential-0').val();
        selector = "#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-" + dependencies[primaryCredential];

        $checkboxes
            .prop("disabled", false)
            .filter(selector)
            .prop({
                disabled: true,
                checked: false
            });
    });
});
```

​
If you have so many checkboxes, you should cache them for increased performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `switch-case` statement like:

```
var credential = $('#edit-submitted-primary-credential-0').val();
$('#webform-component-primary-credential--0').change (function() {
switch (credential) {
   case 35:
      $('#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-47').attr('checked', false);
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-47").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      break;
   case 41:
      $('#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-53').attr('checked', false);
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-53").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      break;
   case 13:
      $('#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-29').attr('checked', false);
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-29").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      break;
   default:
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-47").removeAttr("disabled");
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-53").removeAttr("disabled");
      $("#edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-29").removeAttr("disabled");
   }
```

});

Comment: This isn't equivalent to OP's logic.

Answer (score 0):

I find this one more cleaner. Havent tested the code. You may extend credentials object to use array of val, and keys. You will need to change edit_additional_credentials() implementation as well.

```
$('#webform-component-primary-credential--0').change (function() {
    edit_additional_credentials();
});

var credentials = [
    {
        primary: 'edit-submitted-primary-credential-0',
        additional: [
            {
                key: 35,
                val: 'edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-47'
            },
            {
                key: 41,
                val: 'edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-53'
            },
            {
                key: 13,
                val: 'edit-submitted-additional-credentials-0-29'
            }
        ]
    }
];

function disable_additional_credential(id) {
    $('#' + id).attr('checked', false);
    $('#' + id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

function enable_additional_credential(id) {
    $('#' + id).removeAttr("disabled");
}

function edit_additional_credentials() {

    for (var i = 0; i < credentials.length; i++) {
        var val = $('#' + credentials[i].primary).val();

        for (var j = 0; j < credentials[i].additional.length; j++) {
            if (val == credentials[i].additional.key) {
                disable_additional_credential(credentials[i].additional.val);
            } else {
                enable_additional_credential(credentials[i].additional.val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```